# objective c - How to convert nsdata to byte array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I am working with UIImage conversion to NSData. And I want to convert NsData to Byte Array and post that Byte array to server with the help of json Parser.

If i am passing following type of static string to server it accept and store. Following is just example string syntax. i want follwoing type of byte array to post data to server.

[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7,7,9,9,8,10,12,...]

For above result i am converting image to data as following:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Now i want to convert NSdata to byte array for that i am using following code:

```
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
free(byteData)
```

and i also store this to NSdata. but cant get about result.
I also typed about code with looping but every time it gives **aPNG** as result.

Am i doing any thing wrong in the above code?

Please provide me some help and also request to provide any help for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a byte array (in the C sense of the term), or a JSON-encoded string that represents a list of numeric values?

Comment: Any reason why you're freeing your buffer as soon as you fill it? If you're expecting the buffer to still hold what the NSData object held... you cannot count on it one you free it. Only free it when you no longer need the buffer.

Comment: @udy thanks for your reply but using that way. it is not working.

Comment: @zneak i want to convert My NSData to byte array format as i shown in my question.

Comment: @Hrushikesh Why would you post the data to a server as a list of decimal values? That's pretty inefficient. Why not just post the raw data bytes?

Comment: @rmaddy My client server webservice support only decimal value like above formate so.

Comment: There are easier ways to get an image from an iPhone to a server...

Comment: @GoZoner i know that but i was little tanction for converting it in byte array. Now it Done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for or not. Try:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSUInteger len = data.length;
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len * 3];
[result appendString:@"["];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i) {
        [result appendString:@","];
    }
    [result appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[i]];
}
[result appendString:@"]"];
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Minor remark: If you declare `bytes` as `const uint8_t *bytes` then you don't need the type cast on the rhs.